# Salesforce Notification through reverse proxy

Tags: soap-api, soap, authentication, notification

I am an integration developer working with a Salesforce.com developer.   He is using the Notification functionality 'push' a message using SOAP to our integration platform when an object changes.

This has been in place, and working successfully, for 2 years only requiring certificate maintenance.  On Friday June 12, 2015 our reverse proxy began refusing messages with a 403 error being sent back to SFDC.

The Apache Reverse proxy is using the following directives for authentication:

```
<location />
  SSLVerifyClient optional
  SSLVerifyDepth 10
  SSLRequire (%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq "proxy.salesforce.com")
  SSLCACertificatePath sfdc/ClientAuthentication
</location>
```

We have verified that all of the relevant certificates are valid, and that no changes have been made in our system which would cause these rejections.  Also, we have also verified the configuration objects on salesforce did  not change at this time.

We are not aware of any changes which coincide with our new failures.  Has there been any changes that salesforce might have made to their system that we missed?

The specific error in the apache log file state:

```
[Wed Jun 24 12:10:05 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1765): OpenSSL: Read: SSLv3 read client certificate A
[Wed Jun 24 12:10:05 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1784): OpenSSL: Exit: failed in SSLv3 read client certificate A
[Wed Jun 24 12:10:05 2015] [info] [client 96.43.148.8] SSL library error 1 in handshake (server <SNIPPED>)
[Wed Jun 24 12:10:05 2015] [info] SSL Library Error: 336151574 error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown
[Wed Jun 24 12:10:05 2015] [info] [client 96.43.148.8] Connection closed to child 6 with abortive shutdown (server <SNIPPED>)
```

Other services hosted by the proxy continue to work without issue.  The problem is limited only to SF.

Thank you in advance....